# How is facebook connect pop up window designed?I

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I click on connect to facebook and a pop takes me directly to the facebook domain from the iframe which belongs to mydomain. But after successfull authentication how does it automatically close and get to the event handle?

In other words, whats going on behind FB.login()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
It uses postMessage supported by HTML5 to support cross window cross domain communication!

Answer (score 0):

Once it receives a successful auth key, It will close the dialog window. Just like OAuth works when you get a code on a successful authentication

Comment: Ok.. but how does the parent window get notified? A parent window and child window belonging to different domains cannot communicate rite?

Comment: completely guessing here, but FB could easily have an iframe on the parent window, that iframe would exist on the facebook.com domain, and would contain a script opening the popup. The popup page would only navigate in ways that don't add items in the window history, and would call something like opener.notifyStuff(...) before calling window.close(). At least that's how I'd do it.

Comment: Please do take a look at XDM.. I am guessing if it would work http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/cross-domain-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I havent researched this, but this is my guess: I think Facebook is setting a signed cookie on the client's machine if there is a successful authentication. The Facebook JS library recognizes this cookie when it's set and closes the window.

Comment: Yes.. In the scheme you describe, It could close the window, but  then the parent window cannot be notified of status of the authentication and only way would be to refresh it and then based on the cookie info the js could determin the login status. But the parent window in facebook connect does not refresh!

Comment: There is no reason why it would need to refresh the window. You can use Javascript to check.

Comment: Oh.. I missed to tell you a detail here, closing the window is fine, and once the login is successful, A event is getting fired in the parent window notifying the successful authentication.. Do u think its possible with your description?

Comment: Yes. You would just have to check for the cookie with the parent via Javascript. If the signed cookie gets set, you know you're authenticated.